# How safe it is to list /dev/block for non virtual drives to determine hard disks on the system?

Tags: shell-script, block-device

How safe it is to determine hard disks on the system by using the following approach (I am particularly obstinate in avoiding non-kernel utilities/programs):

```
ls -l /sys/block | grep -v "/virtual"
```

Can I expect /sys file system to always be present in Ubuntu versions higher than 16, as well as RHEL 7 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sysfs` filesystem and `/sys` as its mount point was introduced in the 2.5.xx development kernel cycle. It's been there as standard on every 2.6.xx or greater kernel, on every distribution I know of.

By listing `/sys/block` and filtering out virtual devices, you should get a list of all block devices the kernel knows about.

However, if the system contains any of the following:

- true hardware RAID controllers
- FibreChannel HBAs
- hardware-assisted iSCSI interfaces

then the `sd*` nodes you'll see might not be actual physical disks, but logical RAID sets, SAN LUNs or similar constructs defined deeper in the appropriate storage hardware. If you consider these as equivalent to disks, then you should be fine.

Comment: Practically speaking, at least the discussed method seems more encompassing than the one widely found googling: `sudo hdparm -I /dev/sd?` - which was the one I was using till I spotted today this  will not always hold true...

Comment: Yes, `hdparm` was originally designed to work with IDE/ATA disks only. By the convergence of IDE and SCSI into SAS/SATA and `hdparm` gaining extra functionality over time, `hdparm -I` can now produce meaningful information on many forms of block devices... but still not necessarily all of them. If you are looking for "all things you can put a filesystem on and have the kernel mount it", then `/sys/block/*` is a valid answer. If you are looking for strictly local physical disks, you'll find the simple cases there, but for non-simple cases, you might have to dig deeper still.